# Disable TeX interpreted messages in waitbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

What is the quickest way to disable TeX markup from displaying in messages in a `waitbar`? I was expecting an option like

```
'Interpreter', 'none', ...
```

Comment: Hmm as awlays, the usual way: hChild = get(hWaitbar,'Children'); hTitle = get(hChild,'title'); set(hTitle,'Interpreter', 'none');

Answer (score 9):

The `Interpreter` property is not available for figures I believe (`waitbar` creates a figure object), but you can apply it afterward to the waitbar message:

```
h=waitbar(x,message);
set(findall(h,'type','text'),'Interpreter','none');
```

You could also escape the problematic characters, but that would be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the global Tex Interpreter to `None`, it applies to waitbars as well.

```
 set(0, 'DefaulttextInterpreter', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the object one might change the interpreter directly with the 'dot-notation' (available since R2014b) as in the following MWE:

```
wb = waitbar(0/10,'My_waitbar_string_with_underscores');
wb.Children.Title.Interpreter = 'none';
for i = 1:10
  waitbar(i/10,wb,'My_waitbar_string_with_underscores');
  pause(1);
end
delete(wb);
```

Which changes the interpreter for the title of the axis that is placed inside the waitbar.

Note that if you use a cancel button in the waitbar, the number of children of the object changes and one might have to change

```
wb.Children.Title.Interpreter
```

to

```
wb.Children(2).Title.Interpreter
```